# Guzzle 6 array_merge not working by form params?

Tags: php, guzzle6, guzzle

I am running `guzzlehttp/guzzle` version `6.5.5.` on `PHP 7.3.8` and trying to make a post request.
One of the required fields is `blog`.

So when I do this:

```
$comment = [
    'foo' => 'bar'
];
$data = $comment + ["blog" => $this->blogUrl];
dump($data);
$options = [
    'form_params' => [
        $data,
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ]
];
$response = $this->client->post($url, $options);
```

I get the error that the "blog" fields is missing.

The result of the above dump is:

```
array:2 [
  "foo" => "bar"
  "blog" => "http://jigal.dev"
]
```

But when I do this (notice that I moved 'blog' into the form_params key):

```
$comment = [
    'foo' => 'bar'
];
$data = $comment;
dump($data);
$options = [
    'form_params' => [
        'blog' => $this->blogUrl,
        $data,
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ]
];
$response = $this->client->post($url, $options);
```

The error is gone.

Doing `array_merge($comment, ["blog" => this->blogUrl]` in stead of `$data = $comment + ["blog" => $this->blogUrl];` does not make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first example is equivalent to: `form_params' => [['foo' => 'bar', 'blog' => ...]]`. Note the double square brackets. Edit: oh, well, you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working:

```
$data = ["blog" => $this->blogUrl] + $comment;
'form_params' => $data
```

Instead of
`form_params => [ $data ]`